# Wrong Radio Button is Selected in React on First Click

Tags: reactjs, radio-button

I am building a step system where for each step, the required fields are populated once you get to that step in the form...

I have a particular step that is a collection of options in the form of a radio input, for which the component looks as such:

```
{map(packages, (pkg, index) => {
    return (
    <label style={{
        position: "relative",
        zIndex: 9
    }} for={fieldId + `-${index}`}>
        <input
            style={{
                accentColor: '#3ebd93',
                width: '35px',
                height: '35px',
            }}
            id={fieldId + `-${index}`}
           type={"radio"}
           name={"choose_package"}
            onChange={e => handleInput(e, pkg, index, fieldId)}
            checked={checked || false}

        />
    )
    </label>
    })
}
```

This ultimately renders three radio boxes for which each are wrapped in a label that has a for attribute corresponding to the a specific ID, and the name values are all the same. (I only want one of them to be able to checked)

For example the rendered html for a single input this looks like this (mind you this is wrapped in form):

```
<label for="featured-listing-0" style="position: relative; z-index: 9;">
  <input id="featured-listing-0" type="radio" name="choose_package" style="accent-color: rgb(62, 189, 147); width: 35px; height: 35px;">
</label>
```

Currently it renders three inputs, however whenever I click the *any* input for the *first* time, the same input always gets checked - which on the front end is the last radio input in the DOM. This happens even though I've wrapped it in a label in the `onChange` function it correctly consoles out the clicked input's unique ID. After I click again however, the right radio button is checked.

What is preventing the right radio button to be selected on the first click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue may be in this line:

```
name={"choose_package"}
```

As the name is the same for each radio button they become grouped i.e. selecting one will set the checked state of all others to false. In your loop this means that only the last radio button to be set will stay checked.

If you want to allow them all to be checked then they cannot be in the same group - give them each a unique name.

If you are wanting the grouped functionality then this line

```
checked={checked || false}
```

is problematic as its setting them all to the same checked state.

Comment: I only want one of them to be able to be checked, so I put them all in the same group.

Comment: `checked`  was being set to true by setValue for all of the inputs in the `onChange` function, your answer helped me get there, thanks will accept.